# Dropping inconsequential terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

From $V = \pi r^2h$, we get $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = 2\pi rh, \ \frac{\partial V}{\partial h} = \pi r^2}$.

If $r, h$ change at the same time, we have $V + \delta V = \pi(r + \delta r)^2(h + \delta h)$ which implies $\delta V = \pi(2rh\delta r + h(\delta r)^2 + r^2\delta h + 2r\delta r \delta h + (\delta r)^2 \delta h) \approx \pi(2rh\delta r + r^2 \delta h)$ meaning $\delta V \approx \displaystyle{\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\delta r + \frac{\partial V}{\partial h}\delta h}$.

There's a precise relation $\displaystyle{\delta z =\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\delta y}$ for $z = f(x, y)$ whose proof is an application of chain rule.

Now suppose we do not know the latter and decide to simply compute $\delta V$ like it's done above. How do we know which terms in the expansion of $\delta V$ to drop to get the approximation? We drop the smallest ones, but how do we know, say, $r^2\delta h \not \approx (\delta r)^2\delta h?$

Comment: Do you mean to ask "Why do we drop the term $\pi h (\delta r)^2 $ and keep the term $\pi r^2 \delta h$?  That is, why are we assuming that $\delta h$ is relevant, but $(\delta r)^2$ is not?

Comment: @MarkViola, not quite. I mean to ask how do we know certain terms are substantial enough to keep? What if they are about as small as the dropped terms?

Comment: If one of the linear terms is smaller than one of the quadratic terms, then its contibution would also be negligible.  We retain the linear terms because we do not assign relative sizes to the increments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have for $f(x,y)$ sufficiently smooth

$$\begin{align}
\Delta f(x,y) &= f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)\\\\
&=f_1(x,y) \Delta x+f_2(x,y)\Delta y \\\\
&+f_{11}(x,y)(\Delta x)^2+f_{12}(x,y)(\Delta x)(\Delta y)+f_{22}(x,y)(\Delta y)^2+\text{Higher Order Terms}
\end{align}$$

---

---

Now, one might ask the relative sizes of the linear terms, $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, to the quadratic terms, $(\Delta x)^2$, $(\Delta x)(\Delta y)$, and $(\Delta y)^2$.

If $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are both regarded heuristically as arbitrarily "small" numbers, then certainly $(\Delta x)(\Delta y)$ is "much smaller" than both $(\Delta x)$ and $(\Delta y)$.  And of course $(\Delta x)^2$ is "much smaller" than $\Delta x$ and $(\Delta y)^2$ is "much smaller" than $\Delta y$.  This is the reason for "dropping" the higher-order terms.

---

---

But wait!  What if $\Delta y $ is "much smaller" than $ (\Delta x)^2$.  Well if this is true, then certainly $\Delta y$ is also "much smaller" than $\Delta x$.  All this means is that even the linear term in $\Delta y$ is negligible.

And if $\Delta x $ is "much smaller" than $ (\Delta y)^2$, then certainly $\Delta x$ is also "much smaller" than $\Delta y$.  And all this means is that even the linear term in $\Delta x$ is negligible.

---

---

Since $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are arbitrary, we don't assign relative sizes.  This mandates that we keep both linear terms, even though one of them might be negligible.